# Turn the long generated by MaterialDatePicker into year, month, and day varialbes

Tags: java, android, date, materialdatepicker

I am using the following code:

```java
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> datePickerBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
MaterialDatePicker<Long> datePicker = datePickerBuilder.build();
datePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(selection -> {
    Date selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    selectedDate.setTime(selection);

    // Return and set the text of the date edit text.
    TextInputEditText inputDateEditText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.input_date_edit_text);

    // Set temp variables accordingly.
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(selection), ZoneId.systemDefault());

    int year = dateTime.getYear();
    int month = dateTime.getMonthValue();
    int day = dateTime.getDayOfMonth();

    // Get formatted month name.
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month + 1);
    SimpleDateFormat monthDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.getDefault()); // Use MMMM for full name of month.
    String monthName = monthDate.format(cal.getTime());

    // Put the text into the edittext.
    inputDateEditText.setText("" + monthName + " " + day + ", " + year);

    // Set variables accordingly.
    newEventSelectedYear.set(year);
    newEventSelectedMonth.set(month);
    newEventSelectedDay.set(day);

    System.out.println(selection);
});
datePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "DATE_PICKER");
```

I'm trying to use `MaterialDatePicker<Long>` to display a date picker and then put the values it receives from the user into the `newEventSelected...` variables. I need the month value to be zero-based (so October is month 9) and all the other values to be one-based (so if the user selects "October 20, 2023" in the dialog, the year will be recorded as 2023, month as 9, and the day as 20.

If it helps, I was using the following code, (which worked) before:

```java
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(requireContext());
datePickerDialog.setOnDateSetListener((view12, year, month, dayOfMonth) -> {
    // Return and set the text of the date edit text.
    TextInputEditText inputDateEditText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.input_date_edit_text);

    // Get formatted month name.
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    SimpleDateFormat monthDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.getDefault()); // Use MMMM for full name of month.
    String monthName = monthDate.format(cal.getTime());

    // Put the text into the edittext.
    inputDateEditText.setText("" + monthName + " " + dayOfMonth + ", " + year);

    // Set variables accordingly.
    newEventSelectedYear.set(year);
    newEventSelectedMonth.set(month);
    newEventSelectedDay.set(dayOfMonth);
});
datePickerDialog.show();
```

But I had to switch to `MaterialDatePicker` because `DatePickerDialog`'s interface didn't match my app's.

How do I do this?

### Edit:

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68638574/java-convert-string-and-long-to-datetime), which was recommended to me by `@commonsware`, but had a few questions:

- I was using this code:

```java
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(selection);
System.out.println(instant);

OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("-04:00"));
System.out.println(odt);

int year = odt.getYear();
int month = odt.getMonthValue();
int day = odt.getDayOfMonth();
```

But for some reason, when I select October 20th, 2023 in the dialog, November 19, 2023 is returned. I want September 20th, 2023 to be returned instead. How do I do this?

By the way, I'm using the following to get the formatted month name, if that matters:

```java
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
SimpleDateFormat monthDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.getDefault()); // Use MMMM for full name of month.
String monthName = monthDate.format(cal.getTime());
```

- What does the `ZoneOffset.of("-04:00")` in the code in the answer to the question I mentioned before do? Do I have to change that? What is it's purpose? I want this to be compatible with all users time zones.

Comment: What is the specific problem? If you are trying to determine how to convert a Unix epoch time (typically stored as a `long` value) into something that tells you the various date parts, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68638574/java-convert-string-and-long-to-datetime.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _What does ... `ZoneOffset.of("-04:00")` ... do?_ Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/ZoneOffset)?

Comment: Instead of that `ZoneOffset` you asked about you by all likelihood want `ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefaullt());`. To answer your question, it refers to the mentioned UTC offset, so as used, for example, in New York during summer time/DST; but you want your code to work all year, so you don’t want to use a fixed UTC offset.

Comment: What was your question again, please? If your code misbehaves, in what way then? Which values does it store into `newEventSelected...` if not the right ones? Does it throw any exception, or do you get any error messages?

Comment: I recommend that you stick to java.time, the modern Java date and time API (for example `LocalDateTime`, `Instant` and `ZoneId`) and skip the outdated and troublesome `Date`, `Calendar` and not least `SimpleDateFormat`. For the text for the `EditText` use `dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT))` (or some other format style). To get the month in `newEventSelectedMonth` 0-based subtract 1 from the month from `dateTime` instead of adding 1. Isn’t this all you need?

Comment: Can someone please post an answer? I can't piece together all these suggestions into some working code.

Comment: @OleV.V. Works great except the day of month is too low by 1. When I add 1 and the user has marked the date to be the end of the month, (e.g. they selected October 31), it turns into October 32, which doesn't exist. How can I get this to behave exactly as DatePickerDialog? Maybe I need to get the day of the year (not month), add 1, and then convert it back to day of the month? How do I do this?

Comment: @OleV.V. It works now! Thank you so much. I will post an answer to the question myself with how I solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @OleV.V., I have the answer! I had to use the following code:

```java
// Set temp variables accordingly.
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(selection), ZoneOffset.UTC);

int year = dateTime.getYear();
int month = dateTime.getMonthValue() - 1; // Zero-based month.
int day = dateTime.getDayOfMonth();

// Text for display in inputDateEditText.
String displayText = dateTime.format(Variables.dateTimeFormatter);
inputDateEditText.setText(displayText);
                
// Set variables accordingly.
newEventSelectedYear.set(year);

newEventSelectedMonth.set(month);
newEventSelectedDay.set(day);
```

The key was to use `LocalDateTime` instead of `Calendar`. `Variables.dateTimeFormatter` can be any `DateTimeFormatter`, for example `DateTimeFormatter.ofLcalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)` or `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, u")`. Ole had first suggested `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, but that gave 1 day too early. Instead I had to set the `ZoneOffset` to `ZoneOffset.UTC` and it works great now!

Comment: @OleV.V. I couldn't have done it without your code!